# Widow numbers and \cite seprated from the previous words

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

I did search for this (even asked for help in meta), but found nothing.

Sometimes I need to use tilde `~` to keep things looking good in situations I fell LaTeX should do it automatically. Examples:

1. In the end of a sentence I have "weight 1" and LaTeX breaks the line before the 1, leaving a number ending a sentence, just before the dot, alone in the line.
2. A reference I make with `\cite{something}` is separated from the previous text by another line break: "A says pink is great [1]", and the reference "[1]" goes alone to the other line.

How can I fix this automatically, without recurring to manually putting tildes everywhere?

Comment: You don't. Ties are good, not bad. And sometimes you don't want them.

Comment: a `~` is only one character same as a ` ` a space, so it's no more manual work to mark the non breaking spaces.

Comment: We probably agree to disagree, but in my mind I'm writing a text with spaces and words. Worrying about when to use space or tilde is not related with the content (although sometimes it could be difficult to decide, some others could be automatic. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @egreg, sure that might be true, but in the examples I gave, they could be automated. There are always exceptions.

Comment: You could automate \cite (simply make \cite \unskip any previous skip then add a non breaking one) automating the `weight  1` would be more or less impossible in tex without breaking something else, you need some command or active character to trigger the behaviour.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you provide a complete example? I am afraid my latex knowledge is insufficient to infer one from your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: not really, but someone should feel free to answer if they wish.